# Inserting multiple input data into MySQL from array in nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

The form field from where data is received:

```
<input type="text"  name="result_array[]">
```

The data received from form is:

```
result_array = [ 'one', 'two', 'three' ];
```

I am using this to insert data (mysql npm package) :

```
conn.query('INSERT INTO <table_name> SET ?', result_array, (err, data) => { 
   //anything
}
```

Comment: Fields are required.

Comment: you should also consider sanitizing data from input, not inserting it raw

Answer (score 0):

This is more related to MySQL insert query syntax:

```
conn.query('INSERT INTO table_name (field1, field2, field3) VALUES ?', result_array, (err, data) => { 
   //anything
}
```

Also, make sure to sanitize input data, avoid inserting raw data from form.

Comment: I have a table with fields feature_name, feature_id and the array should insert multiple feature_name's in table with the column name feature_name and not in different fields. Hope you got, what i want to say!‍♂️

Comment: @IcedMonksamyek,  but you need to insert new records right? Or you want to update values in existing records? Keep in mind that feature_id needs to have default value set then, since MySQL would throw an error upon no data inserted. This refers to all fields that don't have set values. 
Can you provide sample of table structure?

Comment: Ya sure `"tbl_course_feature"(`feature_id`, `course_id`, `feature_name`, `feature_desc`)` This is the structure for the table!

Comment: You want to add multiple rows ?

Comment: No @keshavkhandelwal i want to insert multiple data in feature_name which is in array.

Comment: @IcedMonksamyek , in comma seprated as you can't save array in mysql column ?